# Penetrating Vision, TK, and sabotage

Tags: skills, psionics, gurps-4e

I'd like to use PV and TK to cause havoc, disabling guns and power armor, killing power or control to building features (security systems, elevators, etc), and so on. But looking through the books and "teh Google", I can't find any example of how to sabotage things in the GURPS system (even if I don't use TK and/or PV).

Is it assumed that if you know the corresponding skill (Armoury, Electronics Operation, etc) that you can use those skills for ill as well as good? If so, what sort of roll would it be (or what factors should a GM consider in selecting how to resolve the contest)? If not, what skill would be used (and again, how would the contest be resolved)? I wouldn't think that it would be a simple attack roll as PV+TK allows bypassing most of the items typical defenses and thus access to the soft inner workings where a simple tug on a wire should cause a system failure, assuming it was the right one.

I apologize in advance if my Search-Fu was weak as this seems like a common enough scenario (the sabotage itself, not necessarily combined with the powers indicated in this question) that it should be covered, but I simply couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rules for sabotage first appeared in ***GURPS Action 2: Exploits***, as far as I know. That supplement is very useful for all kinds of games that deal with technology, along with ***GURPS High-Tech***. The basic idea is that someone with the skill(s) and tools to repair something can also sabotage it, on the same skill roll. So it would be Mechanic for a car, Armoury for a weapon, Machinist for large machines like an elevator or a compressor, Electronics Repair for electronics, Electrician for house wiring, and so on. Some of these tasks will have substantial positive modifiers (see p345 in the ***Basic Set***), since anyone with Electrician knows how to turn off power, and removing the hard disk from a computer is likewise easy.

If you want to turn something into a trap, so that it only fails when it's being used (e.g., brakes that only fail when a car has reached high speed), you have -2 to your sabotage roll. A Traps roll can reduce this penalty by 1 for a success, or 2 for a critical success. Failing the Traps roll makes the job harder: -1 for failure, -2 for critical failure.

A problem with the PV+TK combination is that TK behaves like a pair of hands. So to (for example) unthread a bolt, you need an ordinary screwdriver that you operate with TK, unless it is so loose that you could unthread it with your fingers, given access. The need for tools is significant for sabotage, and basic TK won't get round that. Some things will be easy, sure, but most vehicles (for example) don't have vital but loosely attached wires, since those would work loose in use.

Consult your GM if you'd like to buy an Enhancement for your TK that removes the need for tools. I suggest that should be "(Cosmic, doesn't need tools for tasks that could be done with hand tools and strength equal to my TK level), +50%", but opinions on that could vary a lot. I got this from ***Power-Ups 4: Enhancements***.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Looks like I might have to invest in Action 2.